# Weighted Job Scheduling using Recursion

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, job-scheduling, recursive-backtracking

I was trying a brute force solution to the [weighted job scheduling](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/weighted-job-scheduling/) problem.

This is what I have tried.

```
const solution = jobs => {
  let maxWeight = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < jobs.length; i++) {
    const endTime = jobs[i][1];
    const weight = jobs[i][2];

    const filteredJobs = jobs.filter(
      (job, index) => job[0] >= endTime);

    const returnedWeight = solution(filteredJobs);
    if (returnedWeight > maxWeight) {
      maxWeight = returnedWeight;
    }
    return weight + maxWeight;
  }
  return maxWeight;
};
```

The input I am using to test my solution is [[1, 2, 50], [3, 5, 20], [6, 19, 100], [2, 100, 200]]. When I execute the the program it returns me 170 i.e when the execution order is 1->2->3. However the expected output is 250 when executed in the order 1->4.

Can anyone please point out as my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop `for (let i = 0; i < jobs.length; i++) {` only runs for i = 0, as you later do `return weight + maxWeight;`. Not sure why you have that line, my guess is you meant to do

```
  if (returnedWeight + weight > maxWeight) {
    maxWeight = returnedWeight + weight;
  }
```